# Understanding and solving a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am studying for a maths exam and came across this practice problem. The $x^2$ in the inner integral is confusing me, like I can't wrap my head around it. How do I go about solving this problem?

$$\int_0^3 \int_0^{x^2} \left(6xy^2 + 12x\right)dy\,dx$$

Comment: Let $f(x)=\int_0^{x^2} \left(6xy^2 + 12x\right)dy$ (with $y$ constant). Then proceed after finding $f(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner integral can be written as
$$ \int_{0}^{x^2} \left(6xy^2 + 12x\right)\, \mathrm{d}y.$$
Observe that $x$ is constant with respect to the variable of integration, which is $y$.  This means that we can treat $x$ as we would any other constant.  Thus we can rewrite this integral as
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x^2} \left(6xy^2 + 12x\right)\, \mathrm{d}y
 &= x \int_{0}^{x^2} \left(6y^2 + 12\right)\, \mathrm{d}y \\
 &= x \left[ 2y^3 + 12y\right]_{y=0}^{x^2} \\
 &= x\left[\left(2\left(x^2\right)^3 + 12\left(x^2\right)\right) - \left(2(0)^3 + 12(0)\right)\right] \\
 &= 2x^7 + 12x^3.
\end{align}
Substituting this back into the original problem, we have
\begin{align} \int_{0}^{3} \left( \int_{0}^{x^2} \left(6xy^2 + 12y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
  &= \int_{0}^{3} 2x^7 + 12x^3 \,\mathrm{d}x \\
  &= \left[ \frac{1}{4} x^8 + 3x^4 \right]_{x=0}^{3} \\
  &= \frac{3^8}{4} + 3^5.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

First handle the integration from inside to outside. When you integrate with respect to $y$ treat $x$ as constant and proceed as usual.

$$\int_0^3 \int_0^{x^2} 6xy^2 + 12x \, dy\, dx=\int_0^3 (2xy^3+12xy)|_{y=0}^{y=x^2} \, dx$$